# paste the content from a csv file to a table in selenium using c#

Tags: c#, selenium

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpUzw.png) I have a table with empty rows initially and I need to copy the content from a csv file and paste in the table. When i tried the below it doesnt work.

```
<table _ngcontent-ced-c250="" class="table table-bordered content-table" style="transform: translateY(0px); top: 34px; width: 750px;"><!----></table>

string text= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(csvFile);
element.SendKeys(text);
```

**Sample content from file**

```
GDS,GDS_SCALE,GDS_X_OFFSET,GDS_Y_OFFSET,GDS_ORIENTATION
gds1.oas,1,0,0,R0,
gds2.oas,1,228100000,0,R0,
```

Comment: Can you update the question with table screenshot link and update the table html as well to check either it contains any other child elements or not.

Comment: attached @image

Comment: You can see the `+/-` button below the table. If you click on `+` is this adding a row to the table?

Comment: but the use case here is to get the content from csv and paste in the table

Comment: By using `JavaScriptExecutor` try to set the `innerHtml` or any other property that can work. I think the use case should be like - read the data from csv and paste in the table, that means each row of csv should be pasted to the table.

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work 

 ((IJavaScriptExecutor)GlobalProperties.driver).ExecuteScript("(arguments[0]).innerHTML = arguments[1];", tableRow, "gds1.oas,1,0,0,R0");

The whole content is pasted in one column

Comment: `tableRow` is the table element? Or this is the row you have by a click on `+` button. Share the Xpath used to identify this.

Comment: table row is the tr of the table which i have created using + button

Comment: If the website is not confidential, please share the URL.

Comment: it is internal, cant be shared

Comment: I hope this can help you instead of reading the data try to set the data to the `td`. [Link](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/handle-dynamic-webtables-with-selenium-in-csharp/)